# How do i iterate over array of json objects using ng-repeat in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i am trying to iterate over array of objects in angular js but i am getting error as cannot set property of undefined even though i had defined it.

```
Please find my code below : 


var app = angular.module('myDemoApp', []);

    app.service('MyTaskService', function($http) {
        var services = {
            userList: userList,
        };
        function userList(req) {
            if (req == undefined)
                req = {};
            return $http({
                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
                method: "GET",
                data: req
            });
        }
        return services;
});


app.controller('MyTaskController', function($scope, MyTaskService) {
    $scope.resp  = {};
    $scope.getPrjDetails = function() {
    try {
                var promise = MyTaskService.userList();
                promise.then(function (sucResp) {
                    try {
                       $scope.resp  = sucResp.data;
                    } catch (exception) {
                        console.log(exception);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                , function (errResp) {
                   console.log(errResp);
                    return;
                });
            } catch (exception) {
                console.log(exception);
                return;
            }
    }
});
```

Find my template :

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="myData in resp">{{myData.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

how can i iterate over all the json values and display in my textboxes in template or my list?

```
<div ng-app="myDemoApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyTaskController">
    <table tyle="float:right;">
        <tr><h3>New Project Form</h3></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Get Project Details</td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>
                <select ng-change="getPrjDetails()" ng-model="select_project" > 
                    <option value=''>Select Project Details</option>
                    <option value='get-details'>Get Project Details</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>New Project Name <span>*</span></td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'> <input type = 'text' ng-model="project_name" ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Assign location to project <span>*</span></td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'> <input type = 'text' ng-model="assign_location" ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Area </td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="area"  ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>City</td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="city" ></td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>State </td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="state" ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Cluster</td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="cluster" ></td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Region</td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="region" ></td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Type <span>*</span> </td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="type" ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Priority <span>*</span></td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="priority" ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'>Name of approver<span>*</span></td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><input type = 'text' ng-model="name_approver" ></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'></td>
            <td class='padding-to-controls'><button ng-click="getPrjDetails()">EDIT</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

please find link to my json i am trying to access :: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: $scope.resp is not defined in your controller

Comment: Where exactly are you calling $scope.getPrjDetails and where exactly is the error occuring you mentioned?

Comment: $scope.resp = {}; i defined my my controller now it gives me error.

Comment: var resp = sucResp.data || {}; error is here.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'resp' of undefined
    at MyTaskController.js:27
    at angular.js:14792
    at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at r.$digest (angular.js:15870)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at g (angular.js:10589)
    at T (angular.js:10787)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:10728)

Comment: i am calling on change of dropdown

Comment: put all relevant html code also

Comment: logic in `promise.then` doesn't make sense

Comment: modified my question please find html code priyesh

Comment: Well first of you expect a `$scope` parameter in getPrjDetails, which you don't provide when calling it. In fact you can just remove that parameter from this function, because have the scope in the controller already. Second it seems that you try to set a property `resp`on some object which doesn't exist. I can't see that anywhere in the code fragments you provided.

Comment: please check now

Comment: This looks like it should be working now

Comment: try parsing response data before you assign it: `$scope.resp  = angular.fromJson(sucResp.data);`

Comment: it displays the list now but how do i assign to my textbox  ?

Comment: your GET data is too much different from html code. Which data your want to display ?

Comment: yes i know just i want to display some title field in my prjct name textbox how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dom is first rendered, angular start searching for `resp.data`, which in your case is undefined and so angular will complain.

You don't need to pass $scope variables to any of the controller functions. They can access it directly.

In your whole code, you are never ever setting `$scope.resp`.

Your html context is way different from what you are trying to do. So I have modified it a bit. Try following code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myDemoApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyTaskController">
    <h3>Feeds</h3>
    <button ng-click="getPrjDetails()">Load</button>

    <div ng-repeat="myData in resp.data">
      <span> {{myData.id}}</span>
      <input ng-model="myData.title" type="text" />
    </div>

  </div>
```

Angular

```
app.controller('MyTaskController', function($scope, MyTaskService) {

  // Required
  $scope.resp = {
    data: []
  }

  $scope.getPrjDetails = function() {
    try {
      var promise = MyTaskService.userList();
      promise.then(function(sucResp) {
        try {
          var resp = sucResp.data || [];

          // You must update $scope.resp.data 
          $scope.resp.data = resp;

          console.log($scope.resp.data);
        } catch (exception) {
          console.log(exception);
          return;
        }
      }, function(errResp) {
        console.log(errResp);
        return;
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      console.log(exception);
      return;
    }
  }

})
```

fiddle [working](http://jsfiddle.net/t3kcwc7y/1011/)

Comment: it is repeating textboxs also.

Comment: i mean i already hav a table how do i do that?  as i tried putting ng repeat to table form disappers no error.

Comment: Please strip down your html with only fields you need

Comment: please find my textboxs above i want to poputlate data in all those.. for example title be my project name ..area be  my userId and so on.. i just needed for sample purpose later on i will update with my genuine information in those textboxes

Comment: you are getting more that one item from api. Do want to repeat the table for all those?

Comment: oh yes. i did it now. :)